# Buscar una secuencia de una lista en otra lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de encontrar una secuencia de una lista en otra lista. Pero no entiendo por qué mi salida es "no".

**all:** no es una solución porque devuelve true incluso si los elementos no están en orden

**set:** no es una solución porque necesito los elementos repetidos

**Script:**

```
fruits = ['banana', 'grape', 'blueberry', 'kiwi', 'raspberry', 'coconut', 'apple']
colors = ['yellow', 'wine', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'brown', 'red']

sequence = ['blue', 'green', 'red']

if sequence in colors:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

**Output:**

> no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es convertir esos array en string y luego comparar la secuencia

```
colors = ['yellow', 'wine', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'brown', 'red']
sequence = ['blue', 'green', 'red']


strColors = str(colors).strip("[]")
strSequence = str(sequence).strip("[]")

if strSequence in strColors:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Resultado:

```
>>>yes
```

**[Demo online](https://www.ideone.com/jNQv5u)**

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que dices, quieres encontrar una determinada secuencia de palabras en otra, en el mismo orden de aparición. Ya has hecho una buena investigación y has descartado algunas opciones que efectivamente no ayudan para esto. Bien, se me ocurre una forma super simple, que conceptualmente es similar a la que te ha dado lois6b: transformar las listas en cadenas y compararlas:

```
fruits = ['banana', 'grape', 'blueberry', 'kiwi', 'raspberry', 'coconut', 'apple']
colors = ['yellow', 'wine', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'brown', 'red']
sequence = ['blue', 'green', 'red']

if ",".join(sequence) in ",".join(colors):
  print("Si")
```

Nota que al convertir a una cadena agregamos un separador entre cada item de la lista, esto es para evitar algún caso como: `['blu', 'egreen', 'red']`, también tener en cuenta este delimitador, no debiera ser un carácter que aparezca en los valores sino este algoritmo eventualmente podría fallar.

Otra forma interesante es recorriendo la lista y haciendo "slice" del tamaño de la que queremos encontrar, de hecho es la lógica más segura, pero también es más lenta que la opción anterior

```
if any(sequence == colors[i:i+len(sequence)] for i in range(len(colors) - 1)):
  print("Si")
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Me gustó mucho la forma haciendo slice, pero es un poco más difícil para mí entender (todavía soy inicante). Pero mi sueño es poder escribir scripts de esta manera. La otra forma es realmente muy simple y funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 2):

Sin hacerlo complicado, te creas una función para comparar dos listas:

```
def compare(lst1, lst2, ini=0):
    n = len(lst2)
    return lst1[ini:ini+n] == lst2
```

La variable `ini` permite comparar la lista `lst2` a partir de un elemento de `lst1`. Así, por ejemplo, con `ini=0` compararíamos desde el primer elemento de `lst1`.

Para conseguir nuestro objetivo, basta ir recorriendo toda la lista y hacer comparaciones:

```
any(compare(colors, sequence, i) for i in range(len(colors)))
```

Se puede hacer mejor. En lugar de comparar todas las posiciones, podemos reducir la comparaciones a las posiciones en la primera lista donde encontremos el primer elemento de la segunda lista, `sequence[0]`. Se puede usar el método `list.index(x)`, pero es algo engorroso trabajar con él cuando se quiere obtener todos los elementos. Conviene más hacer una función que nos dé todas las posiciones coincidentes:

```
def indexes(lst, x):
    return (i for (i,y) in enumerate(lst) if x==y)
```

De este modo, la comprobación quedaría bastante más optimizada:

```
any(compare(colors, sequence, i) for i in indexes(colors, sequence[0]))
```